# How can I get a list of all "likable" Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm exploring the Facebook API for the first time - partially to research a web app idea I have and partially out of pure curiosity. The [Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool has been a great help with most things.

I'm trying to get a complete list of "Likable" pages on Facebook such as: Movies, Music, Books, TV Shows, etc. I understand how to get a list of pages that a user has liked, but I want the entire index of pages that exist.

All of the strings I've worked with so far start with `/username`. Is there another prefix for querying Facebook in general?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible and doesn't exist in the API.
A query like this is way too resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
/search?q={query}&type=page&access_token={app_access_token}
```

with `{query}` as the search string, `{app_access_token}` as your App Access Token, as outlined at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

It's not possible to retrieve or search for whole Page Categories.